# How to type in two text fields simulatenously (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I was unsuccessful in finding a jQuery plugin that allowed me to write in two inputs simultaneously.

I'm trying to write a normal title in one field, and at the same time type in another input write the same text without special characters or spaces.

e.g.

Input 1: This is my Title!

Input 2: ThisIsMyTitle

Comment: Do you want each character from input 1 to appear in input 2 (minus the special characters) **as you type?**

Comment: as you type, if they paste a title in... any condition of that sort, on-the-fly, would be ideal.

Comment: seems duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411235/while-typing-in-a-text-input-field-printing-the-content-typed-in-a-div

Answer (score 10, accepted):

on keyup copy input value from current input into 2nd input, no plugin is required.

```
$("input#first").keyup(function(e){
  var val = $(this).val();
  val = val.replace(/[^\w]+/g, "");
  $("input#second").val(val);
});
```

something like that

Comment: May as well use `this.value` (much cheaper than `$(this).val()`). Also, you should cache `$("input#second")`.

Comment: something like that == not optimal. i actually wrote it while on a support call with lenovo.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myTextInput").keyup(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    text = processText(text);
    $("#secondTextField").val(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("input1").keyup(function() {
  jQuery("input2").val(removeWhiteSpace(jQuery("input1")));
}
```

(pseudo code)

Answer (score 0):

```
​var a = jQuery('input#a'),
    b = jQuery('input#b');

a.keyup(function(){
    b.val(this.value.replace(/[^\w]/g, ''));
});​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

Full code, it will get only letters and numbers and display on the input2 without anything else.

```
$("#input1").keyup
(
    function ()
    {
        $("#input2").val
        (
            $(this).val().match(/[a-z]|[0-9]/gi).join("")
        );
    }
);
```