# While typing in a text input field, printing the content typed in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I have a website where there is a empty box and a input text box.  I want to be able to type something in that input box and have it be printed on the empty box.

### HTML

```
<div class='printchatbox'></div>
```

which is the empty box and

```
<input type='text' name='fname' class='chatinput'>
```

which is the input box.

### CSS

```
.printchatbox 
    {border-width:thick 10px;border-style: solid; 
    background-color:#fff;
    line-height: 2;color:#6E6A6B;font-size: 14pt;text-align:left;float: middle;
    border: 3px solid #969293;width:40%;}
```

If anyone could tell me how to do this I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks

Comment: Is there some other even more elegant way to do it? Just wanting to get the best available options out there.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You use the [`onkeyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onkeyup) event

Searching with ids is a lot easier. Add ids to your elements as follows:

```
<div class='printchatbox' id='printchatbox'></div>

<input type='text' name='fname' class='chatinput' id='chatinput'>
```

JS

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById('chatinput');

inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
}
```

Here is a [Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/mEefW/)

Comment: Both `<div>` and `<input>` tags don't have `id` attribute, so give it first.

Comment: @t_motooka Thanks, I forgot to mention that I added the ids.

Comment: @nunespascal thanks for the solution. But, I found that this doesn't work when we are using it on a textarea with an editor (SimpleMDE, in my case) enabled.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/3kpay/

```
<div class='printchatbox' id='printchatbox'></div>

<input type='text' name='fname' class='chatinput' 
    onkeyUp="document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = this.value" />
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to get this done, possibly the easiest is to use jQuery. In the example below I am using the jQuery `keyUp()` function to listen for keyboard events, then writing the updated value to the `.printChatBox`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class='printchatbox'>CHANGE ME</div>
  <input type='text' name='fname' class='chatinput'>

<script type="script/javascript">
  $('.chatinput').keyup(function(event) {
    newText = event.target.value;
    $('.printchatbox').text(newText);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've posted a working example here: http://jsbin.com/axibuw/1/edit

Comment: I think there is something wrong in your script on top.
<script type="script/javascript"> should be <script type="text/javascript">

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML,

```
<div id='printchatbox'></div>
<br>
<input type='text' id='fname' class='chatinput' onkeyup="annotate()">
```

In JS,

```
function annotate(){
  var typed= document.getElementById("fname").value;
  document.getElementById("printchatbox").innerHTML= typed;
}
```

[Click here for LIVE DEMO](https://jsbin.com/cevuhucimo)

Answer (score -1):

Angular JS does this in two lines of code :

Just import Angular JS as you import other libraries :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js">
```

Then, on you first div (where you are copying from):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myID"> </input>
```

Then, on the place where you will show the content : just write :

```
<div> {{myID}}</div>
```

This is the best solution I have ever found !

Comment: Do not import an entire SPA just to respond to an event. Make sure you're not adding libraries that you dont need to add. If you're already developing a single page app, fine, but for this; it's overkill.

Comment: @joshua.thomas.bird You are right. Add a whole library just for a task is not a good idea.