# Type in two text boxes simulatenously

Tags: c#, textbox

I have come across a similar question in jQuery (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908860/how-to-type-in-two-text-fields-simulatenously-jquery)) and I tried to modify it according to my needs in C#, but I haven't managed to do it. What I want is what the title says, I'd like for a user to type some text in one textbox and for the results to be displayed simultaneously in another. Here's my go at it (obviously, it doesn't work), I tried to pass the arguments of the `KeyUp` event of the first textbox to the respective event of the second one, but it looks like it's not that easy:

```
public mainFrm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.txtFormat.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(txtFormat_KeyUp);
    this.txtNewFormat.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(txtNewFormat_KeyUp);
}

private void txtFormat_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    txtNewFormat_KeyUp(sender, e);
}

private void txtNewFormat_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: User should be able to type in both textboxes? What should happen if user will type in second textbox?

Comment: Users will be allowed to type in both textboxes, yes, but what I've posted above should only happen when the user types in the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will keep the two text boxes synchronized:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        textBox1.TextChanged+=new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);
        textBox2.TextChanged+=new EventHandler(textBox_TextChanged);            
    }

    void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text=(sender as TextBox).Text;
        if(!textBox1.Text.Equals(text)) { textBox1.Text=text; }
        if(!textBox2.Text.Equals(text)) { textBox2.Text=text; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to do this is to just listen to the `TextChanged` event of one `TextBox` and forward the current state to the other

```
public mainFrm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    txtFormat.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
}

private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtNewFormat.Text = txtFormat.Text;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, would this solution update letter per letter, or only after the text in the first textbox was completely typed?

Comment: However this will overwrite completely what was written in the second textbox each time a modification is done in the first. OP have to be careful with that.

Comment: @jmstoker it would update every time the text in `txtFormat` was changed.  So after every letter press and copy operation it would change

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault correct but this seems to be the OP's intent from what I can tell

Comment: It gives me a No overload for 'OnTextChanged' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler' error. And, JaredPar, you're right. That was my intent from the beginning. That's why I tried using KeyUp events.

Comment: @JimIliadis oops, small typo on my part.  Should be fixed now

Comment: I hate to be THAT guy, but it's still not fixed. :( Both textboxes display odd behavior. The second one will only display one character sometimes and the first one nothing for the most part. Thank you for helping me, though.